# How to switch between two different php version with composer

Tags: php, laravel-5, composer-php

I've got a lot of research about it but I found nothing that can help my problem. I'm developing a project for now using `laravel5.1` and I'm using `PHP5.6` version, however I also want to install the new laravel version which is `L5.5` but the minimum PHP requirement is `PHP7.0` and I chose the `5.6` version of PHP in my installed `composer`.

How can I switch this two versions of PHP without reinstalling the composer again and again? So if I work with `Laravel5.1` I can use the composer with `PHP5.6`, otherwise I use `Laravel5.5` with `PHP7` version.

**Note:**
I'm using WAMP Server that has `PHP5.6` & `PHP7` available to use.

Comment: Could you provide more info about your server? Shared hosting or,..? Composer does not control the installed PHP version, so you have to have PHP7 installed on your machine/server in order to use PHP7

Comment: Yes, I already have `PHP7` installed, packaged with WAMP Server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a Windows batch file that calls the composer.phar file using the php7 binary. Let's call the file composer7.bat:

```
@echo OFF
:: in case DelayedExpansion is on and a path contains ! 
setlocal DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
c:\path\to\php7\directory\php.exe "%~dp0composer.phar" %*
```

Save the file along with the originally installed composer.bat file, mine is located in C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\ directory.

Now call the php7 composer with the new command:

```
composer7 require ...
```

Comment: Hi Scriptonomy! What is this command for `composer7 require ...` ?

Comment: it's a sample use case. You install a package with it. right?

Comment: Ooh great, so I use `composer7 ...` instead of `composer require...`?

Comment: Is this the whole code that I need to use `@echo OFF
:: in case DelayedExpansion is on and a path contains ! 
setlocal DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
c:\path\to\php7\directory\php.exe "%~dp0composer.phar" %*`? May I request the explanation?

Comment: Just calling phar file with php7 binary. that's all it's doing.

Comment: Oh, ok. One more thing, I tried `php -v` command and then `php5.6` printed instead of `PHP7`. Do you have any idea why `php5.6` printed out?

Comment: because php5.6 is listed in Windows environment PATH variable.

Comment: Cool! I changed it and it took effect with `PHP7`. Great, its working now. This is exactly the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: @Jonjie you prob don't need it but if you don't wanna switch b/w versions from env PATH variable yourself. I just made a tool for windows to do it easily by cli. Check it out https://github.com/back2Lobby/switcher